# Removing Duplicate Products

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module

I am working with the following code, which displays all products from all orders for the logged in customer. Problem is its duplicating the products I only want 1 of each product to display.

When I do vardump($uniuqProductSkus); I get the following printed out under each product

array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "96" }

array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "9902" }

array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "9902" [1]=> string(2) "96" }

I believe its like this because I ordered "96" and "9902" in individual orders and then I ordered "96" and "9902" together in one order

I've tried array_unique in a couple of different places but never get the right results

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer       = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array(
'like' => $customer_email
));

foreach ($collection as $order) {
//do something
$order_id = $order->getId();

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 

$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();

// -----------------Initialized an empty array to store unique products SKUS
$uniuqProductSkus = array();
foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
 //item detail  
    //Check if product already exists  in uniuqProductSkus array, means it is duplicate, do not process, continue
    if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        // product is not yet found, push  into the uniuqProductSkus array
        array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku());
        $_product                 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        $product_small_image_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200);
        $product_thumbnail_path   = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150);
        $summaryData              = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($item->getProductId());

        echo "<li>";

        echo "<div class='previous-name'><p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
        echo $item->getName() . "</a></p></div>";

        echo "<div class='previous-image'><a href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
        echo "<img src='" . $product_small_image_path . "' />";
        echo "</a></div>";

        echo "<div class='previous-rating'>";
        echo "<p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "#product_tabs_review_tabbed'>Review this beer now</a></p>";

        echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . '% Would buy again <br/>';

        echo "<div class='rating-box' style='float:left;'>";
        echo "<div class='rating' style='width:" . $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . "%'></div></div>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class='previous-button'>";
        echo '<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(\'';
        echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
        echo '\')"><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>';
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div>";

        echo "</li>";

        var_dump($uniuqProductSkus);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This thread has the answer in it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165160/removing-duplicate-products-from-array/28165784?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer to my question

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer       = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();
$customer_id = $customer->getId();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array(
'like' => $customer_email
));



$uniuqProductSkus = array();

foreach ($collection as $order) { 

    $order_id = $order->getId(); 
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); 
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 
        foreach ($ordered_items as $item) 
        { 
        if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) { 
        continue; 
        } else { 
            array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku());
```

Answer (score 1):

Will Wright ,use  `getAllVisibleItems` instead of `getAllItems` .it is better ways

Comment: Even though @Amit didn't provide a code example, this is the way to go.